# The addition table for $\mathbb Z/4$ - modular arithmetic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

"Write down the addition table for $\mathbb Z/4$ "

Could someone please give one or two hints? And what does them mean with $\mathbb Z/4$? They have never used that notation before. Do them just mean the integer divided by $4$ or what? I don't have any answer to this question so I would need someone to check my solution after the hint(s) :)

Comment: It's called modular arithmetic.

Comment: Does it mean $\mathbb{Z}/(4\mathbb{Z})$? In this case, they may mean to add $0,1,2,3$ plus $0,1,2,3$ (there are $16$ cases to consider).

Comment: @mathse: I dont know. It does only say "Write down the addition table for $\mathbb Z/4$ "

Comment: @isabellh Now you have an answer. Do you know what $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addition table for $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
& 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 0 \\
2 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 1 \\
3 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
$$

and the multiplication table for $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
& 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \\
2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & \\
3 & 0 & 3 & 2 & 1 & \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: sorry i did not see your answer. Thanks alot! But are you sure that they meant Z_4 with Z/4 ? thanks again

Comment: Probably. It's one of a few notations for cyclic groups.

Comment: thanks. Then it was pretty easy, since addition and multiplacation in Z_4 is the same as, for an example:
4x=5 in Z_4 is same as 4x congruent 5 mod 4 right?

Comment: Yeah. Basically if you're given $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4$, then compute their sum/product as you normally would, and then mod by $4$ to land back in  $\mathbb{Z}_4$.